# Possible to check if input (int or double) is null?

Tags: java

I am trying to develop a project at my university with JavaFx, and I wonder if there is a way to check if integer or double is empty or null?

E.g:

```
public void setNumber(int input) {
    this.gramsTobacco = gramsTobacco;
}
```

Then I want to validate if the input actually is an integer. Is there any method for doing this?

E.g:

```
public  void checkNumber(int num) {
    if (num is empty) {
        throw new .... "Input must be a number"
    }
}
```

Comment: Input will always be an int. An int can never be null, nor can it be a non-int.

Comment: primitives (e.g. int, char, byte, etc) cannot be null.

Comment: And they cannot be empty.

Answer (score 2):

An `int` **by definition** will always be a number, and not `null` since it's [a primitive type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). The same applies to `double`, `float` and several other types.

In contrast, an `Integer` (note the upper case) can be null, but if it isn't, then it's also guaranteed to be a number, just like `Double`, `Float` and others.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Integer` class instead of a primitive int

To check null simply compare `n != null`

To check type you can use the .class() method of object class